# Laravel Filament - how to swap out the "record" id in a "/{record}/edit" route

Tags: laravel-filament

I have set up standard list, create, edit pages for a record. By default, the getPages() function links the routes, passing in a placeholder for "record:

```
public static function getPages(): array
{
    return [
        'index' => Pages\ListUserFamilies::route('/'),
        'create' => Pages\CreateUserFamilies::route('/create'),
        'edit' => Pages\EditUserFamilies::route('/{record}/edit'),
    ];
}
```

...the "record" in this case will is passing in the user Id. However, due to a more complicated relational database, I don't want to pass the ID in, I want to pass in a different value. How do I pass that value through instead? eg....

```
public static function getPages(): array
{
    return [
        'index' => Pages\ListUserFamilies::route('/'),
        'create' => Pages\CreateUserFamilies::route('/create'),
        'edit' => Pages\EditUserFamilies::route('/{someothervalue}/edit'),
    ];
}
```

thanks

Comment: So then you are using another column from ```UserFamily``` model as route key ?

Comment: yes. I don't think I bothered in the end.

Comment: Issue got fixed ?

Comment: Figured out how to use the main Id instead